# Software to control TOR browser

Tags: java, tor

I want to create a tool for automatically search on google some keyword defined by the user and give back the results list to the user.
As i don't want to use any proxy or pre-built anonymous networks, i choose to drive this searches through the TOR browser.

So, i need to build my tool and let him "drive" the TOR browser to:
- open the TOR browser;
- insert data in Google search box;
- extract the result list and show it to the user;
- refresh the IP address of TOR browser and proceed with the following search.

Do i have to build something in Java and let the tool interfacing with TOR browser?
Is there any other way to control TOR browser, simulating a user who open it, open Google, search the keywords, etc?

Many thanks for your time.

Comment: Dear All, why negative votes without explanations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Search for `java TOR libraries`

For example, consider this library:

- [Orchid TOR client](https://subgraph.com/orchid/index.en.html)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. So, in your opinion i can write a tool in java and drive the TOR browser giving the necessary information?

Comment: Java tor libraries allow you to do that. For instance: http://sourceforge.net/projects/silvertunnel/